# Get error when scaffold MS Access database (Could not find installable ISAM)

Tags: ms-access, entity-framework-6, db-first, jet-ef-provider

I am using Entity Framework 6 to manage an MS Access database (mdb file).
I am now using this project (bubibubi / EntityFrameworkCore.Jet)
But in their example, it uses a * .accdb file while I'm using a * .mdb file.
When i execute:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\database.mdb';Database Password=mypass" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet
```

I get this message: `Could not find installable ISAM.`

I don't know and don't find what i need to do.

I'm use C#, Console App, .Net Framework 4.6.1

Edit:
If i use the new Access database files (*.accdb) that work fine.
But this is a legacy project and i need manage a old access files (*.mdb)

Comment: You can try to use a newer oledb provider and still access to mdb file. I also found this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/209805/you-receive-a-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-message-or-some-fi

Answer (score 0):

Try using the driver for mdb files and no quotes:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\database.mdb;Database Password=mypass" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet
```

But it may still fail as you put the file in the root of the system drive. Use a subfolder.

Comment: The file is not in the root folder ... I just delete a long path...
But i got the same error using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;

Comment: Found an old thread that seems to provide the answer, if any.